# Making a draft of tic-tac-toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
player1 = True


def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)
    return board


def place(board , player1 , position ):
    if player1 == True:
        player1 = False
        if board[position] == 0:
            board = position
        elif board[position] != 0:
            print("False , place taken 1")
    else:
        if player1 == False:
            if board[position] == 0:
                board = position
            elif board[position] != [0, 0]:
                print("False , place taken 2 ")
    return board
```

Function call:

```
place(board=create_board() , player1=1 , position=(0,0))
```

Here is my code, in this code there is a lot going on however there is one part i could not get it right . In the bold section , i am trying to replace

```
([0,0,0],
 [0,0,0], 
 [0,0,0])
```

to

```
([1,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0])
```

May i know , how can I do this please ... Thank you !

Comment: Hello cobralim, would you indicate the section with something other than bold formatting? That seems to get lost in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're mistakenly changing the `board` variable to `position` inside the if statements

```py
if board[position] == 0:
    board = position
```

you should change the value inside `board` at index `position`

```py
board[position] = 1   # for player 1
board[position] = 2   # for player 2
```

i've also cleaned the code a little bit

```py
def place(board , player1 , position ):

    x = 1 if player1 else 2

    if board[position] != 0:
        print(f'False , place taken {x}')

    else:
        board[position] = x

    return board
```

Comment: I would like to ask , why am I getting { TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable } this error ?

Comment: could you please tell where in the code you're getting this error, 
I assume you're getting it in the `board[position]` statement. if thats the case then you're probably passing `None` as the `board` argument of the function

Comment: I'm so sorry  , what do you mean passing None as the Board argument ? and how do you fix this ?

Comment: what im saying is that you might be passing a `None` object as the `board` of the function, where as you should pass an `np.array` object, this link might be helpful http://net-informations.com/python/err/nonetype.htm,  im only assuming that you're getting this error because of this, i cant be sure until you tell me where it is occurring,

Comment: Yup , the error that I am getting from is from the line"if board[position] != 0"

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning your board to your position information with `board = position` and I think you mean `board[position] == 1`

```
def place(board , player, position ):
    if board[position] == 0: #if the position is unclaimed
        board[position] = player #claim it for the player
    else:
        print(f"place was already taken by player {board[position]}")
    return board

#call using the player number
place(board=create_board() , player=1 , position=(0,0))
```

This function would give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to update your board in `board = position` you are actually updating the whole board with your pair of coordinates.

What you really want is to pinpoint the exact position in your two-dimensional array that you have to update to store an occupied cell. You could archieve that changing that line with

```
board[position] = 1 # occupied cell
```

However, as Hammad said in another answer, it would be convienient to change your

```
0 for unoccupied
1 for occupied
```

and having to rely on knowing whose turn is ongoing at the moment, to

```
0 for unoccupied
1 for occupied by player one
2 for occupied by player two
```

so you always know who occupied that cell.